# Is "Dynamic dispatch" works differently in .Net Core 3 and .Net 4.7.2?

Tags: c#, dynamic

The code below produces different results in dotnetfiddle.net. We also see some diffetence in tests behaviour Pls see pictures. Any idea?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;                   
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public class Validator<T>
    {
        
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        dynamic instanceValidated = Enumerable.Empty<int>();
        GetValidator(instanceValidated);
        instanceValidated = string.Empty;
        GetValidator(instanceValidated);
    }
    public static Validator<T> GetValidator<T>(IEnumerable<T> _)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Enumerable Overload " + typeof(T).ToString());
        return new Validator<T>();
    }   
    public static Validator<T> GetValidator<T>(T _)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Generic Overload " + typeof(T).ToString());
        return new Validator<T>();
    }
    

}
```

[image: run in .Net 4.7.1]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, dynamic dispatch didn't change between the versions -hopefully-.

The implementation of `Enumerable.Empty<T>` changed in .NET 3.0 for performance optimization. Check these issues [1](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27552), [2](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2034) and the [pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/31025).

This change is mentioned in [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/) blog post with an accompanying benchmark.

Comment: This is correct answer. To prove I changed my test program not to use Enumerable.Empty
With this change the results are correct and are the same in Core and .Net 4.71
The change is in line 14:
dynamic instanceValidated = new bool[0];